# The answer may not make sense to you

Tags: word, knowledge

I am

> Half an idea
>
> Fifth of a cm
>
> Partly a reminder
>
> Fully a doctor
>
> And a desired statue

Who am I?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Might 'you' actually be:

> **ME**?

*Half an idea*

> ME is half of **[MEME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme)**. (Either half, in fact...)

*Fifth of a cm*

> ME makes up 20% of the 10-letter word 'CENTI**ME**TRE'.

*Partly a reminder*

> ME makes up *part* of the words '**ME**MO(RANDUM)', '**ME**MORY' and '**MEME**NTO'.

*Fully a doctor*

> M.E. is an abbreviation for [**M**edical **E**xaminer](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/ME).

*And a desired statue*

> An '**[Emmy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Awards)**' (say it out loud: "M.E."!) is an award for excellence (in the form of a statuette) desired by many in the television industry.

And as for the title, well, the answer may not make sense to '*you*', but...

> ...it does to **ME**!